# grep command inside EOF doesn't seems to be executing on remote hosts [UNIX BASH]

Tags: bash, unix

Here is the chunk of code for reference:-

Output:
I have checked the variable values using echo and those looks fine.
But what I want do achieve is searching logs on remote hosts using grep which does not give any output.

```sh
for dir in ${log_path}
do
    for host in ${Host}
    do
        if [[ "${userinputserverhost}" == "${host}" ]]
        then
            ssh -q -T username@userinputserverhost "bash -s" <<-'EOF' 2>&1 | tee -a ${LogFile}
            echo -e "Fetching details: \n"
            `\$(grep -A 5 -s "\${ID}" "\${dir}"/archive/*.log)`
            EOF
            fi
            break
    done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Paul for spending time and coming up with suggestions/solutions.

I have managed to get it working couple of days back. Would have felt happy to say that your solution worked 100% but even satisfied that I got it sorted on my own as it helped me learn some new stuff.

FYI - grep -A 5 -s "${ID}" "${dir}"/archive/*.log - this will work but only by using shell built-in 'declare -p' to declare the variables within EOF. Also, I read somewhere and it is recommended to use EOF unqouted as it caters variable expansion to remote hosts without any trouble.
Below piece of code is working for me in bash:

```sh
ssh -q -T username@userinputserverhost <<-EOF 2>&1 | tee -a ${LogFile}
   echo -e "Fetching details: \n"
   $(declare -p ID)
   $(declare -p dir)
   grep -A 5 -s "${ID}" "${dir}"/archive/*.log
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

First, remove all the crap around the grep.
Second, you're overquoting your vars.
Third, skip the "bash -s" if you can.

```
ssh -q -T username@userinputserverhost <<-'EOF' 2>&1 | tee -a ${LogFile}
   echo -e "Fetching details: \n"
   grep -A 5 -s "${ID}" "${dir}"/archive/*.log
EOF
```

Fourth, I don't see where `$ID` is set...so if that's being loaded on the remote system by the login or something, then *that* one would need the dollar sign backslashed.

Finally, be aware that here-docs are great, but sometimes here-strings are simpler if you can spare the quotes.

```
$: ssh 2>&1 dudeling@sandbox-server '
>   date
>   whoami
> ' | tee -a foo.txt
Fri Apr 30 09:23:09 EDT 2021
dudeling

$: cat foo.txt
Fri Apr 30 09:23:09 EDT 2021
dudeling
```

That one is more a matter of taste. Even better, if you can, write your remote-script to a local file & use that. And of course, you can always add `set -vx` into the script to see what gets remotely executed.

```
cat >tmpScript <<-'EOF'
   echo -e "Fetching details: \n"
   set -vx
   grep -A 5 -s "${ID}" "${dir}"/archive/*.log
EOF

ssh <tmpScript 2>&1 -q -T username@userinputserverhost | tee -a ${LogFile}
```

Now you have an *exact* copy of what was issued for debugging.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your inputs. 
I already tried using 'grep' the way you've suggested above and it is not working. 

$ID and $log_path are userinputs and i have backslashed both.

added set -vx now. This is what I am passing now in my script : 
grep -A 5 -s "\${ID}" "\{dir}"/*.log

I see this on terminal : + grep -A 5 -s '${ID}' '{dir}*.log'

not sure but could it be the case that the value of variables are not getting called on remote hosts due to EOF?

Comment: backslash quoting the dollar signs means they are *not* variables. You are telling the parser the dollars signs are just literal dollar sign strings, not variable indicators. Removing the dollar sign on $dir also made it just a string. Maybe you should show us where these values are set in your code? I mean, `$dir` is set in your loop, right? Take the backslash off that, put the dollar sign back. Where's ID coming from?

Comment: I've passed it with "\${dir}" only. Missed $ while posting here. $ID is a user input from terminal and $dir will contain a column of values which is taken from an external ".properties" file. That column has log directories where I want to perform search using grep based on "\${ID}" over multiple remote hosts.
I feel issue is using these variables inside EOF as i exclusively used echo for ${ID} & ${dir} before grep. Upon execution the value of these two variables was not displayed. echo works when used outside of EOF. 
NOTE: I have 4 case statements each having EOF with same piece of code.

Comment: Response to one more of your questions - value for the ${ID} and ${dir} is defined/taken outside the EOF block. I have searched a lot about EOF usage and some have suggested to unqoute EOF to allow variables expansion over remote hosts which I also did. Nothing worked out so far. This is kind of socking me now.

Comment: `grep -A 5 -s "${ID}" "${dir}"/archive/*.log` ***NOT*** `grep -A 5 -s "\${ID}" "\${dir}"/archive/*.log`! Fix that first. If that doesn't help, post more of the code so we can see why.